# make SKSpriteNode without texture

Tags: xcode, swift

I can't get the SKSpriteNode to show up in my scene with Swift.

Here is my code involving the node from the didMoveToView function:

```
let block = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

block.position = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)

    self.addChild(block)
```

It doesn't throw up any errors but I don't see the block showing up in my scene. Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem occurs because of the different sizes of the GameScene and the GameViewController. the GameScene-size is way to small at default.

To resolve that, just add the following line in your `GameViewController`-file in the `viewDidLoad` method after the line : `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

Also to set the node in the middle of your screen, add the following line to your didMoveToView-method:

```
block.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
```

That way, your node will be in the center of the screen.

Comment: That was definitely it! Thanks!

Comment: Also, what then is the default scene size that is obviously too large for my iphone5S? Does it even matter if I use positional references like the one you suggested?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Just don't forget to add this line to every new GameViewController you make.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't see it because the scene scale mode is AspectFill. The scale mode determines how the scene is mapped to the view. You can find it in the GameViewController.swift in the viewDidLoad function and change it or remove it.
The node's default position is CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0) which means the middle of the node is at that position which is at bottom left corner of the screen. Try playing with the values to see what happens.
I hope i helped you.
Good luck!